# Attempted import error: 'unstable_useId' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils' (imported as 'useId')

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I've just spent 3h trying to find a solution by myself, but I'm defintely stuck.

I'd like to use the Mui Autocomplete component, but whatever I try I get this message:

```
Failed to compile

./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/esm/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js
Attempted import error: 'unstable_useId' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils' (imported as 'useId').
```

I already checked that my core and lab were up to date, but they are:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.11",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.50",
```

And the weirdest is that it works like a charm on CodeSandBox with the very same setup...

No idea if this is a clue or not, but I noticed that, in the folder `utils`, almost every single file with a `.js` extension has its "clone" with `.d.ts` extension. Actually, in this folder, my `unstable_useId.js` doesn't have its `.d.ts` one, so... Might it be the problem?

Thanks a lot ! I hope I've been clear enough :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying @keikai.

Anyway, meanwhile, as it was working on CodeSandBox, I tried to isolate the problem... I work on a mac, so I tried to get it work on an other computer which runs Ubuntu: no problem; then on windows: no problem either...

I ended by removing all material-ui librairies from my project on the Mac, then install them back again: Now it works... So no clue on what was wrong, but if you have any thoughts, I'd be happy to understand what could happen there...

Answer (score 5):

change your @material-ui/lab module's version
FROM `"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.50"`
To: `"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.46"`

Comment: worked for me with `@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.45` and `"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.1",`